# JPA : infinite fetch children

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue with two entities relationship, they call each other and I guess I get an inifite fetch :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "domaine")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Domaine implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "lien_domaine_specialite",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="domaine_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="specialite_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Specialite> specialites = new HashSet<>();


@Entity
@Table(name = "specialite")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Specialite implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "specialites")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Domaine> domaines = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private Domaine domaine;
```

The problem occured when I added this relationship ahd and when :

```
@ManyToOne
private Domaine domaine;
```

And when i load a Domaine entity like this :

```
Select domaine from Domaine domaine left join fetch domaine.specialites where domaine.id = ?1
```

Is there a way to tell `Specialite` not to load `Domaine` when I don't need to?

Answer (score 2):

JPA easily handles cross references. The entity that was loaded during current JPA context will not be loaded again. What is the issue you are facing ?
I suppose you enter infinite loop when trying to serialize the graph into json. JSON processing library indeed will enter infinite loop if you don't use  `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` (Jackson specific)

Comment: You can use `@Lazy` annotation to load references on demand, but it's not related to infinite loop.